# Java classpath file reference by string

Tags: java, classpath, filepath

I need to reference a file in the classpath purely via the string value.

This is the code which can't be changed:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName),
            CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
            CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
            CSVParser.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, 1)
```

`new FileReader(fileName)` calls `new FileInputStream(fileName)` which in turn calls `this(name != null ? new File(name) : null)`. As the `name` is not null, this boils down to `new File(name)`. The issue with this is, that the file I need to reference is a classpath resource(`src/main/resources/filters/filterfile.csv`).

I tried a few ways to reference this file purely by path, like

- > src/main/resources/filters/filterfile.csv
- > /filters/filterfile.csv
- > classpath:/filters/filterfile.csv

but none worked, as I always get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` (which is understandable).

**So the question is, is it possible to reference a file in the classpath purely by the string? And if so, how can this be done?**

---

As it might help:

The application is a web app which will run on a tomcat 9 server. So it would kind of be possible to hardcode the path. The issue that this causes is running the application in eclipse then, as the paths wont match at all.

Comment: The *easiest and most compatible* way to do this is probably to read the resource from the classpath and store it in a temporary file and pass the name of *that* temporary file to the method. One of the issues is that resources on the class path may or may not be represented by files on a local disk (they might be in a jar file or loaded from a remote URL, in both of those cases they wouldn't exist as files on the disk).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have added some more info which might help. Regarding your suggestion with the temporary file. As the paths are set during initilization, I see no way to hook into it. I would need to manually initialize that part of the application. And if I go that way, then I can also directly set the right filename via `getClass().getResource("/filters/filterfile.csv").getFile()`. While this could work, it would be far more convenient to have spring simply autowire all the stuff and resolve the filenames with some magic. Though I am open to suggestions (yours already helped)